# API to get District, State and Country name from City name

Tags: javascript, api

I want to implement drop down what have auto complete facility for `city name` . and other drop down value automatically fill for district, state and country.

Is there is any api available for it?

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Comment: yes off course but all api give it's reverse you have to select country first then state then district and then city. But i want only select city and other value fill automatically

Comment: That's the logical order, Why do you want to do it city first? There can be many cities with the same name which makes it hard.

Comment: Would you like to add specific cities OR allover the world? because browsers may hanged or unresponsive with the large data set.

Comment: I want to add cities for specific single country

Comment: Try https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ but try to implement it by autocomplete method otherwise, loading all the countries at once will create a problem.

Comment: @ChintanKukadiya: what api did you say to get state district panchayath type in india.. plz i need these informations in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Google Maps Api, Well it definitely works try looking at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Google Maps Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) ?

All you have to do is google "API for places" and find it !